# Picture frames - iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera, image

I'd like to be able to take a picture (camera or library) and overlay something like a picture frame on it, then save it back to the camera roll. Should I be looking into OpenGL?or, what?

Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need anything except Quartz for that. Look into `CGBitmapContext`, `CGContext`, `CGImage`, `UIImage`. There's also a function to store images in the album: `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`

The way to go is:

1. Get a `UIImage` from `UIImagePickerController`.
2. Build a context using `CGBitmapContextCreate`
3. Draw the image in this context: `CGContextDrawImage`
4. Draw whatever you want on top of that
5. Use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` to create a CGImage from the context
6. Use `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]` to get a `UIImage` from the `CGImage`
7. Use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save the augmented image.