# How can I add a picture frame to an UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I am working on an iphone application where I want to add a different frame(e.g. black grit, oldtime, etc) to an image and save that image with that frame.

Is it possible in iphone application. Please give me suggestion.Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @sarah: bro is any idea What i will do ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525609/picture-frames-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890781/adding-picture-frame-to-a-photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354811/how-can-i-take-an-uiimage-and-give-it-a-black-border).

You need to implement following code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

Comment: Link only answer. First link dead. :-(